# Exporting 16 bit image with Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, accelerate-framework

I would like to export a 16 bit image and I ahve the following code for it

```
let bv = malloc(width * height * 4)!
var db = vImage_Buffer(data: bv,
                               height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                               width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                               rowBytes: width*2)
//        vImageConvert_PlanarFtoPlanar8(&sourceBuffer, &destBuffer, 1.0, 0.0, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
vImageConvert_PlanarFtoPlanar16F(&sourceBuffer, &db, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
let bp = bv.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
let p = CGDataProvider(data: CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                bp,
                                                                width * height,
                                                                kCFAllocatorDefault))!

let cgImage = CGImage(width: width,
                      height: height,
                      bitsPerComponent: 5,
                      bitsPerPixel: 16,
                      bytesPerRow: width,
                      space: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.linearSRGB)!,
                      bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue),
                      provider: p,
                      decode: nil,
                      shouldInterpolate: false,
                      intent: .defaultIntent)!

let savePath = self.documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("camera")
let sURL = savePath.appendingPathComponent(String(format: "image.png")
if let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(smoothedSceneDepthURL as CFURL, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil) {
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, nil)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
}
```

Apple documentation says those values for bitsPerComponent and bitsPerPixel are correct for iOS  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101)

But I get the following error:
 `[Unknown process name] CGImageCreate: invalid image bits/pixel or bytes/row.`

I am able to export an 8 bit image in grayscale and can post the params if required btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 16 bits per pixel, then there will be `2*width` bytes per row:

```
                  bytesPerRow: 2 * width,
```

Comment: Just found the mistake .. thanks .. had to set `  bytesPerRow: 2 * width` and `CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy` with `height * width * 4`

Comment: A quick question .. if it is bpc and 16 bpp 1 bit is ignored ?  How are the channels set ?

Comment: The most significant bit is ignored (that's what `noneSkipFirst` means).